# C#: Storing a reference to an array location in an object

Tags: c#, reference

I have a c# object that sets the values of 2 floating point numbers. I have many such objects.
I would like to store these floating point numbers in an array. So the layout would be something like this:

Given a float array: float[] vec = new float[6]

Object 1 sets the values of vec[0] and vec[1]
Object 2 sets the values of vec[2] and vec[3]
Object 3 sets the values of vec[4] and vec[5]

How can I store references on the objects so they will access the correct vector element? I could store an index, but in the old-fashioned c++ world I could store a pointer directly into array.

Comment: Your requirement clearly states that the object contains 2 floating point numbers, so the next step would to create an instance of a class (similar to `Point`) that holds 2 floating point values.

Comment: I actually said my object *sets* the values of two floating point numbers. The numbers themselves are stored in an array

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an index. I was exploring the possibility of doing this another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I need to use a C-style pointer to the middle of an array, I just make a generic struct that contains a reference to the array and the current index, and use that.  Feel free to steal my code:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/10/references-and-pointers-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 1):

C# is specifically designed so that you cannot store references to array elements or other 'non-root' memory locations in safe, managed code.  Having such references would significantly complicate garbage collection and this capability in C is a known potential culprit for introducing nasty bugs.  For instance, you can allocate an array on the stack in C and pass a reference to an array element.  If that reference is kept around after the stack is unwound, it now points to an arbitrary location and writing to the reference could result in data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a structure like `PointF`:

```
PointF[] points = new PointF[3];
Console.WriteLine("X:{0}, Y:{0}", points[0].X, points[0].Y);
```

Or you can create your own structure:

```
public struct Vector
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```